# Where to place HTML for RPi

Tags: javascript, html, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a simple web page. It uses html and javascript to check on the status of garage doors, and provides a button to toggle the garage door.

OK, so how do I deploy this html file on the RPi so I can open that HTTP: page?

Let's say my RPi is at 192.168.2.126. For now, I'll access it locally on the LAN (If I can do that, I can figure out how to access the page from the internet....)

...update.. I have Apache installed and running. It works.

Comment: You'll need to have a web server of some kind on the RPi, like Apache.

Comment: From http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/htdocs-folder-in-apache-web-server-904992/: "Have a look at your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file at the variable DocumentRoot. That points to where your 'root' directory for your webserver is, normally /var/www/html."

Comment: I've muddled through and put the html file inside /var/www in its own folder, then I reference http://192.168.2.126/GarageDoor/GarageDoors.html. Works so far.... Thanks